# Cleanest format for writing javascript objects

Tags: javascript

What is the cleanest format for writing javascript objects?

Currently I write mine in the following format

```
if (Namespace1 == null) var Namespace1 = {};
if (Namespace1.NameSpace2 == null) Namespace1.NameSpace2 = {};

Namespace1.NameSpace2.Class1 = function(param1,param2){
     // define private instance variables and their getters and setters
     var privateParam = param1;
     this.getPrivateParam = function() {return privateParam;}
     this.publicParam1 = param2;
}

Namespace1.Namespace2.Class1.prototype = {
     publicParam1:null,
     publicFunction1:function() {/* Function body*/}
}
```

That format works well right now, as the YUI documentation software is able to parse it, and the comments and give back good documentation.  But what it doesn't provide is a clean way to declare static global methods within the namespace.  I am also wondering if there is a cleaner way to declar private variables as well.

My question is, is anyone out there have a cleaner way of defining javascript objects than this, and if so, why is your method better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The module pattern may help you out here:

```
 var Namespace1 = Namespace1 || {};
    Namespace1.Namespace2 = Namespace1.Namespace2 || {};

    Namespace1.Namespace2.Class1 = function(param1, param2) {
        // define private instance variables and their getters and setters
        var privateParam = param1;
        this.getPrivateParam = function() { return privateParam; }
        this.publicParam1 = param2;

        return {
            init: function() {
                alert('hi from Class1');
            }
        }
    } ();
```

You can read more about it here: http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/

```
    Namespace1.Namespace2.Class1.init();
```

Comment: Great link, and since I am a YUI guy, definitely fits with my style, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4):

First of all, if you don't know if `Namespace1` is defined, use `typeof this.Namespace1 !== "undefined"`, as accessing Namespace1 will throw an error if it's not defined. Also, undefined properties are `undefined`, not `null` (though `undefined == null`). Your check will fail if something is actually **null**. If you don't want to use `typeof` for checking if properties are undefined, use `myObject.property === undefined`.

Also, your second example has invalid syntax. Here is what I think you wanted to do:

```
Namespace1.Namespace2.Class1.prototype = {
     publicParam1    : null,
     publicFunction1 : function () {/* Function body*/}
};
```

Comment: On the namespace note, I don't actually get an error.  Although I can see why your suggestion is much better practice and probably less likely to fail across different browsers.  Currently that method works with IE 6+, FireFox, Sarari and Opera.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly rewrite the first two lines to this:

```
var Namespace1 = Namespace1 || {};
Namespace1.Namespace2 = Namespace1.Namespace2 || {};
```

The rest of the looks ok.  The private variable is pretty much how everyone does it. Static methods should be assigned to the `prototype`, as you have done.

Do take care redefining the *entire* prototype for an object though, since it will prevent you from a common pattern of `prototype`-based inheritance.  For instance:

```
// You inherit like this...
Sub.prototype = new Super();
obj = new Sub();

// Then you overwrite Sub.prototype when you do this:
Sub.prototype = {foo:1, bar:2}

// Instead, you should assign properties to the prototype individually:
Sub.prototype.foo = 1;
Sub.prototype.bar = 2;
```

Comment: Good idea on the namespace as well.  As for the prototype rewriting, it doesn't cause me too many issues as I use YUI's extend utility which allows me to do inheritance as its intended.  However, without this functionality, I can see re-writing the prototype being problematic.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following function:

```
jQuery.namespace = function() {
    var a = arguments, o = null, i, j, d;
    for (i=0; i<a.length; i=i+1) {
        d = a[i].split(".");
        o = window;
        for (j=0; j<d.length; j=j+1) {
            o[d[j]] = o[d[j]] || {};
            o = o[d[j]];
        }
    }
    return o;
}
```

Then I can use this function to create a namespace just like this:

```
$.namespace("jQuery.namespace1");
```

Once I've created the namespace I can declare functions or whatever you want inside it:

a function:

```
$.namespace1.asyncRequest = function() {
    [function body]
};
```

a constant:

```
$.namespace1.OFFSET = 10;
```

an object:

```
$.namespace1.request = { requestId: 5, protocol: 'JSON' };
```

I think it's simple and elegant :-)

Bye,
Alex